# awk log2 division/ ratio zero

Tags: awk, divide-by-zero

I have a **csv** file that looks like this:

```
ID1              ID2         AVG1     AVG2         
ENSG00000207447 RNU6-2    0.101431  0.163308     
ENSG00000207427 SNORA51   0.096551  0            
ENSG00000201784 SNORD14A  0.068653  0.0320985    
ENSG00000207315 SNORA28   0         0.01936      
ENSG00000207787 MIR98     0         0
```

I want to calculate the **log2** ratio of `AVG1` and `AVG2` and print it next to the AVG columns for each line so that it looks like this:

```
ID1              ID2       AVG1         AVG2       log2Ratio
ENSG00000207447 RNU6-2    0.101431  0.163308     2.0632577007
ENSG00000207427 SNORA51   0.096551  0            inf
ENSG00000201784 SNORD14A  0.068653  0.0320985    7.105015172
ENSG00000207315 SNORA28   0         0.01936      0
ENSG00000207787 MIR98     0         0            inf
```

I've tried

```
$ awk 'NF> 2 { ratio =($3/$4)/log(2) ; print $0, ratio }' testlog2.csv > testlog2_2.csv
and
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {if ($4==0) {print $0, "inf"} else {print $0, ($3/$4)/log(2)}}' testlog2.csv > testlog2_2.csv
```

but `awk` keeps crashing whenever the denominator is 0. If you have any suggestions how to get round it, that would be excellent.

Comment: Your second example works fine to me. What "crashing" do you get?

Comment: Hi, I get the fatal error: awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=testlog2.csv FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: just remind,  gawk `log()` is natural logarithms `ln`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've had a look how to convert ln to log2, would this formula work: log2(n) = ln(n)/ln(2) = log(n)/log(2)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrithm#Change_of_base  this is a common trick when programming with `log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, you should print the head line separately.

to verify it:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{print "A"/"B"}'                                                                                                                                           
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

You could change your awk line into:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR==1{print;next}{if ($4==0) {print $0, "inf"} else {print $0, ($3/$4)/log(2)}}' file
```

I didn't change much in your codes, basically copy and paste, just add the `NR==1` part.

**NOTE**

if you run the code, you will see that the output is not same as your expected (example in your question). I hope your logic `($3/$4)/log(2)` is correct.

the output with `NR==1{...}` fix:

```
ID1              ID2       AVG1      AVG2
ENSG00000207447  RNU6-2    0.101431  0.163308   0.896061
ENSG00000207427  SNORA51   0.096551  0          inf
ENSG00000201784  SNORD14A  0.068653  0.0320985  3.08567
ENSG00000207315  SNORA28   0         0.01936    0
ENSG00000207787  MIR98     0         0          inf
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I'm checking the formula.

Comment: `($3/$4)/log(2)` is mistaken, because it is just a rescaling of the ratio: you probably meant `log($3/$4)/log(2)` for the binary logarithm of the ratio. For instance, in the first row with `AVG1` equal to 0.10 and `AVG2` equal to 0.16, the ratio is less than 1, whence its log must be *negative* (and should work out to -0.687097).